# How to test function defined on window object in Jest and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to test a call to a function defined on the global window object. I have looked at multiple examples but am still not able to run a simple test case.

Api.ts

```
import "./global.d";
const verifier = window.Verifier;

export class Api {
  constructor(private readonly id: string) {}
  public fetchData() {
    return new Promise<object>((resolve, reject) => {
      verifier.request({
        request: {
          id: this.id
        },
        onSuccess: (data: object) => {
          resolve(data);
        },
        onFailure: () => {
          reject("Error!");
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Api.test.ts

```
import { Api } from "./Api";

let windowSpy: any;

describe("Test Apis", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    windowSpy = jest.spyOn(window, "window", "get");
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    windowSpy.mockRestore();
  });
  it("should call the function", () => {
    const mockedReplace = jest.fn();
    windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
      Verifier: {
        request: mockedReplace
      }
    }));
    const api = new Api("123");
    api.fetchData();
    expect(mockedReplace).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

global.d.ts

```
import { Verifier } from "./verifier";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    Verifier: Verifier;
  }
}
```

verifier.d.ts

```
type RequestPayload = {
  request: {
    id: string;
  };
  onSuccess: (data: object) => void;
  onFailure: () => void;
};
type verifyCode = number;

export interface Verifier {
  request: (requestPayload: RequestPayload) => verifyCode;
}
```

I have also created a codesandbox example for easy reference
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-mccarthy-2jj622?file=/src/verifier.d.ts

Comment: Why depend on globals when using modules?

Comment: @DanielA.White I know it's weird but that's the project requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your import order.

When you `import { Api } from "./api";`, you run `const verifier = window.Verifier;`, which, at the time, is `undefined`.

If you change the order of the imports and spies it should work as expected:

```js
import { RequestPayload } from "./verifier";

const mockRequest = jest
  .fn()
  .mockImplementation((requestPayload: RequestPayload) => 1);

jest.spyOn(window, "window", "get").mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    Verifier: {
      request: mockRequest,
    },
  } as unknown as Window & typeof globalThis;
});

// // // // //

import { Api } from "./api";

// // // // //

describe("Test Apis", () => {
  let api: Api;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    api = new Api("123");
  });

  it("should have valid function", () => {
    expect(typeof api.fetchData).toBe("function");
  });

  it("should call the function", () => {
    api.fetchData();

    expect(mockRequest).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

You could also think about using `window.Verifier` directly, making the tests a bit cleaner:

```js
export class Api {
  constructor(private readonly id: string) {}
  public fetchData() {
    return new Promise<object>((resolve, reject) => {
      window.Verifier.request({
        request: {
          id: this.id,
        },
        onSuccess: (data: object) => {
          resolve(data);
        },
        onFailure: () => {
          reject("Error!");
        },
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```js
describe("Test Apis", () => {
  let api: Api, mockRequest: jest.Mock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();

    mockRequest = jest
      .fn()
      .mockImplementation((requestPayload: RequestPayload) => 1);

    jest.spyOn(global, "window", "get").mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        Verifier: {
          request: mockRequest,
        },
      } as unknown as Window & typeof globalThis;
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    api = new Api("123");
  });

  it("should have valid function", () => {
    expect(typeof api.fetchData).toBe("function");
  });

  it("should call the function", () => {
    api.fetchData();

    expect(mockRequest).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @doublethink, but unfortunately it's still not working.

Comment: Thanks again @doublethink. Your second example Works... 
In fact, the change in the order of imports in the first example is also not required. Jest automatically hoists all mock calls to the top of the module before all the imports. Learned that today.
As you suggested, calling window.Verifier directly worked.